# Send the image on API using post method from imagepicker

Tags: iphone

I want to make a registration form, here I have taken all UITextField data in string and send on the api using post method but I don't know how to send image on api with all data?

Comment: What you use for sending a data AFNEtworking? And what type of your api is?

Comment: Yes i am using AFNetworking , my API is Post type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following code Snippet

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:       [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"]];

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"YourValue",@"ValueName",@"YourValue",@"ValueName", nil];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img_Picture);

[manager POST:@"Your URL" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"logo" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure %@, %@", error, operation.responseString);
}];
```

Where parameters contains all your textfield's data.

And Logo is image parameter name which is used in api coding.

Comment: Where img_Picture is your UIImage